# Given two points and a set distance calculate the domain of all possible paths.

Tags: geometry, path-connected, fixed-points

If I am given two points the shortest path between them is a straight line. However, I am told there exists some path between Point A and Point B that is d long. I believe there is technically an infinite amount of paths one could take from point A to point B that is d long. However, I believe it is possible to calculate a shape that represents the total domain of all these paths.

Currently, I have considered modifying the trajectory of a projectile function or calculating an arc circle between the two points based on the known distance.

I was wondering if anyone on the stack exchange community had heard of such a thing or if they know if such a thing is possible. I also do not know if this question meets community guidelines so please let me know if I can improve upon it.

Comment: Assuming a flat ground with two points $A$ and $B$, and $d$ that is long enough, the points whose total straight line distances to the two points equal to $d$ form an ellipse. Then all possible paths would be within that ellipse.

Comment: @peterwhy that's a good insight perhaps I can than define the ellipse as an equation using what I already know from the two points and d. Thank you. I do wonder if there is a custom shape that would best suit the problem? If do you have any ideas on how I could go about creating it?

Comment: The first comment gives you the answer: an ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$ is minimal shape containing all paths. If you don't like that, take any shape containing that ellipse.

Comment: Good to know thank you.